# Pass Data from Annotation to next VC

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, annotations

I have a map with annotations and these annotations have a detail button. This button opens up the drawer from the pulley library, which is just a new ViewController overlaying the map. But I want to give this VC the information of the title of the annotation. I got this so far:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView{
        let annotation = self.map.selectedAnnotations[0] as MKAnnotation!
        print(((annotation?.title)!)!)

        //These lines belong to the drawer from the pulley library
        (parent as? PulleyViewController)?.setDrawerPosition(position: PulleyPosition(rawValue: 2)!)
        let detailVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BarDetailVC") as UIViewController

        (parent as? PulleyViewController)?.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: detailVC, animated: true)
        //Here I want to give the upcoming VC the title of the annotation
        let vcbar = BarDetailVC()
        vcbar.barname = ((annotation?.title)!)!
    }
}
```

Printing the annotation gives the right title of it. But when I print the variable `barname` inside the BarDetailVC it is empty. I think this way doesn't seem to work. I can't work here with segues because of other issues with the pulley lib here.

Comment: `let vcbar = BarDetailVC()` That's a whole new object `vcbar`, you know that, right? How is it linked to `detailVC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `let vcbar = BarDetailVC()` you are creating a whole new ViewController which is not used.

How about:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView{
        let annotation = self.map.selectedAnnotations[0] as MKAnnotation!
        print(((annotation?.title)!)!)

        (parent as? PulleyViewController)?.setDrawerPosition(position: PulleyPosition(rawValue: 2)!)
        let detailVC: BarDetailVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BarDetailVC") as BarDetailVC
        detailVC.barname = ((annotation?.title)!)!
        (parent as? PulleyViewController)?.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: detailVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

If it doesn't you could think about using delegates.

Comment: No it doesn't work. It says that detailVC has no member called barname. It doesn't work with any other var from the BarDetailVC either. Thats why I tried to put that reference with vcbar in the first place. What do you mean with using delegates can you explain that ?

Comment: Ok no I just didn't read your code carefully. It works !! Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: I am happy I could help ^^ Could you please mark my answer with the green tick :P would be cool